# Tab Bar Only on Second View

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I'm trying to create an iOS application. The first view is just a home screen that segues into the second view, which has all the content and the tab bar. I'm trying to add the tab bar programmaticaly, so I'm doing it through the app delegate file. This is a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

    let vc1 = UIViewController();

    let vc2 = UIViewController();

    let tabBarController = UITabBarController();
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [vc1,vc2];
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible();



    return true
}
```

The problem with this is that it tries to add the tab bar to the home screen. I wish to add it to the second view. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Prepare For Segue Method:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

let vc1 = UIViewController();

let vc2 = UIViewController();

let tabBarController = UITabBarController();
tabBarController.viewControllers = [vc1,vc2];
segue.destinationViewController = tabBarController;//This doesnt work
```

Comment: You are making tab bar as root view controller.

Comment: if you want to add it to second view controller, you need to do it in the prepareForSegue of the HomeScreen VC which is just before moving to the second VC.

Comment: how you are presenting the second VC ?

Comment: It is a collection view, and I have a custom segue to it

Comment: okay, then you need to add the tab bar in the prepareForSegue method

Comment: Can you show the code related to prepareForSegue or customSegue ?

Comment: I'm working on it right now, I'll post it in two minutes

Comment: @Mr.T  I updated the question

Comment: can u add the code and update the question ?

Comment: after u add tab bar to second view, how many tabs does the tab bar controller should have ?

Comment: its supposed to have two tabs

Comment: In that case why dont you simply hide the tab bar in your first view controller ?